# Debugger broken when updating anaconda 3.6.5 to 3.7.1 with VS Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, anaconda

My code runs fine without debug mode, then when I run in debug mode I get the following error on the first import (regardless of what I import first):

```
Unable to open '&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;': File not found 
(file:///c:/foo/bar/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;).
```

I have upgraded anaconda before multiple times and never had this issue.

Edit:
I fixed the issue by installing the new anaconda (python 3.7.1), and installing an older version of VS code 1.25.1. So this appear to be a problem with VS codes newer builds.

Comment: See the issue tracker on the VSCode github page: https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/312

Comment: @James This doesn't help, I unchecked the break points box and it did nothing. I looked at "Just My Code" Issue 194: https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/194 which is linked in the issue you posted, and it sounds like they know of the issue and think they fixed it.